# a2enconf not installed?

Tags: server, apache2, php

I want to install adminer.php in a server to have access to a database installed there.

There are a Laravel project and a Wordpress installed there and fully working.

Following [these instructions](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2014/06/install-adminer-manually-ubuntu-14-04/) to install adminer I find I need to enable a configuration

```
sudo a2enconf adminer.conf
```

But I get:

```
sudo: a2enconf: command not found
```

Without sudo:

```
The program 'a2enconf' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

WHAT? I got apache2 already

```
apache2 -v
```

Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server built:   Jul 27 2017 15:20:24

What is going on here? Are there any problems with my running projects if I reinstall apache?

Comment: Did you try to reinstall Apache `sudo apt update && sudo apt install --reinstall apache2`?

Comment: This is not a game breaker. a2enconf does nothing else but making a 'ln -s'. It creates a symbolic link from sites-available to sites-enabled. Go into sites-enabled and look for yourself. If you don't know how to do it, just answer and I'll show it to you. You simply don't need it....

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the path:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin"
```

After this you can use the command.